# How to manipulate background color of a row and a table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table, row

I have an application whereby when the user clicks on Add New Item button rows are added dynamically using Javascript and each input field in the row added dynamically has a unique id and this works fine.

When any number on the table on the left is clicked it is populated dynamically in the row on the left. When another number on the table on the right is clicked it populates on the single input on the right (after the plus icon).

When I hover over the 1st row the background color changes to green including the corresponding match on the table on the left which works fine.

Am trying to add a logic whereby 
a.) if the **user clicks on Add New Item button to add a new row (the row is added according to the format of the 1st row)**.

b.)  After the user clicks on any td number on the 2 tables (right and left) and their values are populates in the rows dynamically (value on the left table populates in the row before + sign and value in the right table populates in the right table after + sign), when the user hovers over the values on the rows their background color should change immediately and conform to the values of the tables they were previously chosen from...

NB ~ Basically I want **the behavior on the 1st row (after mouseover when inputs are filled from respective tables) to be simulated across proceeding rows that are added dynamically after the button is clicked**.

JsFiddle link: [Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9cjyh348/)

~ Kindly assist on this quite challenging task..

**Javascript code which is commented to show my steps in the task**

```js
//Add row input fields dynamically on button click
// Starting number of inputs
let count = 5;

// Wrapper
const wrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper");

document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const container = document.createElement("div");

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // Increment the count to ensure that it is unique
    count++;

    // Create new `<input>` element
    const input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.name = count;
    input.size = "4";
    input.id = `inp${count}`;

    container.appendChild(input);

    // Optional: add empty whitespace after each child
    container.append(document.createTextNode(" "));
  }
  wrapper.appendChild(container);
});
//END creating rows dynamically

let currentInput = 1;
let bonusInput = 1;

//Left table on click event
$("#table1 td").on("click", function(event) {
  //gets the number associated with the click
  let num = $(this).text();
  //Populate it in 1st row input fields (before plus sign)
  $("#inp" + currentInput++).attr("value", num);
});

//Right table on click event
$("#table2").on("click", function(event) {
  //gets the number associated with the click
  let bon = event.target.textContent;
  //Populate it in 1st row input fields (after plus sign)
  $("#bonus" + bonusInput++).attr("value", bon);
});

//Manipulate background colors of rows with corresponding tables they were
//selected on hover in and hover out
$("input").hover(
  function(event) {
    let parent = $(this).parent();
    $(parent.children()).each(function(index, element) {
      let num = $(element).val();
      //console.log(num);
      if (num) {
        //Change input color on hover
        $(this).css("backgroundColor", "green");
        //Change left table bgcolor on hover
        $("#table1 td").each(function() {
          if ($(this).text() === num) $(this).css("backgroundColor", "green");
        });
        // $("#table2 td").each(function() {
        //     if ($(this).text() === num) $(this).css("backgroundColor","green");
        // });
      }
    });
  },
  function(event) {
    //Change input color on hover out
    let parent = $(this).parent();
    $(parent.children()).each(function(index, element) {
      $(element).css("backgroundColor", "white");
    });
    //Change left table bgcolor on hover out
    $("#table1 td").each(function() {
      $(this).css("backgroundColor", "orange");
    });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `.hover()`-helper, the event-listeners are created and bound to the items that are available at the moment of creation. All inputs that are created after that are ignored. You have to assign/activate the hover-behaviour for them, when you create/append the new inputs.

```js
//Add row input fields dynamically on button click
// Starting number of inputs
let count = 0;

// Wrapper
const wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');

document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', () => {

  // Increment the count to ensure we have unique inputs
  count++;

  const container = document.createElement('div');
          
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    let input_index = (count * 5) + i;
    
    // Create new `<input>` element
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'text';
    input.name = input_index;
    input.size = '4';
    input.id = `inp${input_index}`;

    $(input).hover(onInputHoverIn, onInputHoverOut);

    container.appendChild(input);
            
    // Optional: add empty whitespace after each child
    container.append(document.createTextNode(' '));
  }
  
  // Bonus-Input
  container.append(document.createTextNode(' + '));

  let input_index = count + 1;
  // Create new `<input>` element
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'text';
  input.name = `bonus${input_index}`;
  input.size = '4';
  input.style.marginLeft = '20px';
  input.id = `bonus${input_index}`;
  
  $(input).addClass('bonus-input');
  $(input).hover(onInputHoverIn, onInputHoverOut);

  container.appendChild(input);
  
  wrapper.appendChild(container);
});
//END creating rows dynamically

let currentInput = 0; 
let bonusInput = 0;

//Left table on click event
$("#table1 td").on('click',function(event){
  if (currentInput >= ((count + 1) * 5)) {
    return;
  }
  currentInput++;
  //gets the number associated with the click
  let num = $(this).text(); 
  //Populate it in 1st row input fields (before plus sign)
  $("#inp" + currentInput).attr("value",num); 
});

//Right table on click event
$("#table2").on('click',function(event){
  if (bonusInput >= (count + 1)) {
    return;
  }
  bonusInput++;
  //gets the number associated with the click
  let bon = event.target.textContent;
  //Populate it in 1st row input fields (after plus sign)
  $("#bonus" + bonusInput).attr("value",bon);
});

//Manipulate background colors of rows with corresponsing tables they were
//selected on on hover in and hover out
function onInputHoverIn(event) {
  let parent = $(this).parent();
  $(parent.children()).each(function (index, element) {
    let num = $(element).val();
    let isBonus = $(element).hasClass('bonus-input');
    //console.log(num);
    if (num) {
      //Change input color on hover
      $(this).css("backgroundColor","green");
      if (!isBonus) {
        //Change left table bgcolor on hover
        $("#table1 td").each(function() {
          if ($(this).text() === num) $(this).css("backgroundColor","green");
        });
      } else {
        //Change left table bgcolor on hover
        $("#table2 td").each(function() {
          if ($(this).text() === num) $(this).css("backgroundColor","green");
        });
      }
      }
    });
}
function onInputHoverOut(event) {
    //Change input color on hover out
    let parent = $(this).parent();
    $(parent.children()).each(function (index, element) {
      $(element).css("backgroundColor","white");
    });
    //Change left table bgcolor on hover out
    $("#table1 td, #table2 td").each(function() {
      $(this).css("backgroundColor","orange");
    }); 
};
$("input").hover(onInputHoverIn, onInputHoverOut);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  width: 50%;
  height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color:orange;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight:bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Table on the left -->
<div style="width: 140px; float: left;">
  <table id="table1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<!-- Rows on the right-->

    
<!--2nd table-->
<div style="width: 140px; float: left; margin-left: 12px;">
  <table id="table2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<!-- Rows on the right-->

<!-- Make sure each input has a unique id-->
<div style="clear: both;">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="1" size="4" id="inp1" value="">
      <input type="text" name="2" size="4" id="inp2" value="">
      <input type="text" name="3" size="4" id="inp3" value="">
      <input type="text" name="4" size="4" id="inp4" value="">
      <input type="text" name="5" size="4" id="inp5" value="">  +
      <input class="bonus-input" style="margin-left: 20px;" type="text" name="bonus1" size="4" id="bonus1"  value="">  
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="btn">Add new input group</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot ,, Just a polite request .. When I click Add new input group button to add rows,,, I want even the last input field after + sign to be added ( so as to make it exactly as the format on the 1st row)...

Comment: I updated my answer. The elements and their look are now equal for each row added. Also the behavior is fixed, so that table2 gets highlighted. Also prevented that the counters increase when clicking table1 or 2 and there is no more inputs to fill with numbers. *Just a side-note: a good idea is to put all styling into css and just toggle custom classes for that element, so the javascript code is more readable and easier to work with.*